# InvalidCastException when retrieving a record from LiteDB

Tags: c#, litedb

I inserted a record via LiteDb.Shell.exe and when I try to retrieve the record in my code, it throws an `InvalidCastException`. If I try to find the record via the shell, I get an `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.`

Here's my model

```
public class Query
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string Hash { get; set; }
    public string[] Arguments { get; set; }
    public int[] PrintoutIds { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the shell command I used to insert a record

```
db.queries.insert {FilePath: "C:/Temp/Reporting Test.sql", Hash: "8074458BDE071C6B05A6EE1C718EC29CC92C89A2967D6E314EADEB0BA60F270E", Arguments: ["Tenant_ID"], PrintoutIds: [1]}
```

Here's the shell commands I used to try to get the record back

```
> db.queries.find
[1]: {"_id":{"$oid":"5a0ef5219996a32e14886d6b"},"FilePath":"C:/Temp/Reporting Test.sql","Hash":"8074458BDE071C6B05A6EE1C718EC29CC92C89A2967D6E314EADEB0BA60F270E","Arguments":["Tenant_ID"],"PrintoutIds":[1]}
> db.queries.find PrintoutIds contains 1
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
> db.queries.find PrintoutIds contains "1"
> db.queries.find $.PrintoutIds[*] contains 1
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
> db.queries.find $.PrintoutIds[*] contains "1"
```

Here's the code I'm using to retrieve the record

```
public IEnumerable<dynamic> DoStuffWithAQuery(int id)
{
    using (var reportDatabase = new LiteDatabase("C:/Stuff/Database/Reporting/Reports.db"))
    {
        var queryCollection = reportDatabase.GetCollection<Query>("queries");                                   
        queryCollection.EnsureIndex(x => x.PrintoutIds, "$.PrintoutIds[*]");
        Query query;
        try
        {
            // The next line throws an InvalidCastException.
            query = queryCollection.Find(x => x.PrintoutIds.Contains(id)).Single();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("Only one query can be mapped to a printout",
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        return DoSomeStuff(query);
    }
}
```

Here's the full stacktrace I get

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Specified cast is not valid.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:

at
 lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object ) at
 LiteDB.BsonMapper.DeserializeObject(Type type, Object obj, BsonDocument value) at
 LiteDB.BsonMapper.Deserialize(Type type, BsonValue value) at
 LiteDB.BsonMapper.ToObject(Type type, BsonDocument doc) at
 LiteDB.BsonMapper.ToObject[T](BsonDocument doc) at
 LiteDB.LiteCollection`1.<Find>d__17.MoveNext() at
 System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
 ReportService.DoStuffWithAQuery(String tenantName, Int32 id, Object parameters) in C:\C# Workspace\MyProject\ReportService.cs:line 35 at
 SyncInvokeDoStuffWithAQuery(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc& rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc& rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc& rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc& rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc& rpc) at
 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 thinks here

First, if your strong class use _id as an integer, you can't use shell with ObjectId (deafault). Try:

`db.queries.insert { ... } id:int`

Now, your document will be insert with auto-id as `Int32` (`_id: 1`). This will avoid your mapper error here:

`query = queryCollection.Find(x => x.PrintoutIds.Contains(id)).Single();`

Second, it about "contains" keyword. In shell, "contains" works as `String.Contains`. Shell use `Query.Contains(string field, string text)`. So, you can't pass an Int as "text".

Your query, in shell, must use `=`

#### With no index

> db.queries.find $.PrintoutIds[*] = 1

#### Or, create an index

> db.queries.ensureIndex PrintoutIds using $.PrintoutIds[*]

#### Now, using indexName

> db.queries.find PrintoutIds = 1

But..... when you are writing Linq expressions, `Contains` can be from `String` or from `IEnumerable`. If are from `String`, works as normal `Query.Contains`, but if are from an `IEnumerable`, works with `Query.EQ`.

```
// QueryVisitor.cs : 152

// Contains (String): x.Name.Contains("auricio")
else if (method == "Contains" && type == typeof(string))
{
    var value = this.VisitValue(met.Arguments[0], null);

    return Query.Contains(this.GetField(met.Object, prefix), value);
}
// Contains (Enumerable): x.ListNumber.Contains(2)
else if (method == "Contains" && type == typeof(Enumerable))
{
    var field = this.GetField(met.Arguments[0], prefix);
    var value = this.VisitValue(met.Arguments[1], null);

    return Query.EQ(field, value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change Id in your class Query to Query_Id and will work

```
public int **Query_Id** { get; set; }
```